# How can I go back after flashing an unsuccessful file with no backups in HTC EVO 3D GSM?

Tags: htc-evo, rom-flashing

I have accidentally flashed a file (http://www.box.com/s/k8ch8jjne6y2aa5g4lg9) that allows full arabic in HTC EVO 3D **CDMA**. When I reboot, the phone stops on the HTC white screen.

The problem is that I haven't made a backup in recovery before. I don't know how to go back. I have wiped all dalvick, data and cache but the problem persists.

My device is on Bootloader Unlocked + CWM recovery + S-ON

Comment: Are you able to get to the recovery console? Have you tried flashing the GSM version of the ROM on top of the CDMA one?

Comment: Yes, I am. About the GSM version, I will check.

Comment: Can't find the GSM version. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply flash any compatible GSM ROM to your phone (look for one on xda-developers forums) via recovery console after performing another round of wipe. Whatever incompatible drivers and radios were introduced by the CDMA version will be overwritten, and the phone should boot successfully. After that you can continue searching for the ROM with full Arabic support.